# MS Word 2010 - database links no longer prompting on open

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-access

I have numerous documents that used to automatically link to a database upon opening with the statement:

> Opening this document will run the following SQL command:
>
> `SELECT * FROM C:\somepath\somefile.mrg`
>
> Data from your database will be placed in the document. Do you want to continue?

My staff have updated the formatting of those documents (font, margins etc.) and now those documents, when opened, are not providing the prompt.  Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Check whether any symbolic link created in between the file and executing application the link is broken